# More efficient and shorter way to declare this array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I've seen more efficient and shorter ways to declare 2d arrays but so far all I've found are for integers, and I can't seem to apply it to chars.

For example,

```
char[][] magicSquare = {{'P', 'L', 'O', 'T'},{'R', 'A', 'V', 'E'},{'E', 'V', 'E', 'N'},{'Y', 'A', 'R', 'D'}};
```

Here is my best try so far. Thank you.

```java
magicSquare = new char[4][4];

magicSquare[0][0] = 'P';
magicSquare[0][1] = 'L';
magicSquare[0][2] = 'O';
magicSquare[0][3] = 'T';

magicSquare[1][0] = 'R';
magicSquare[1][1] = 'A';
magicSquare[1][2] = 'V';
magicSquare[1][3] = 'E';

magicSquare[2][0] = 'E';
magicSquare[2][1] = 'V';
magicSquare[2][2] = 'E';
magicSquare[2][3] = 'N';

magicSquare[3][0] = 'Y';
magicSquare[3][1] = 'A';
magicSquare[3][2] = 'R';
magicSquare[3][3] = 'D';
```

Comment: what is it that you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Here was my failed attempt. Thank you!
```
char[][] magicSquare = {{'P', 'L', 'O', 'T'},{'R', 'A', 'V', 'E'},{'E', 'V', 'E', 'N'},{'Y', 'A', 'R', 'D'}};

Comment: Conceptually, integers and character arrays are defined the same way, you can also define single arrays on one line, for example `magicSquare[0] = new char[] {...}`

Comment: and what is the error you get?

Comment: The one you mentioned and @Pirate answer is the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It should work.

```
char[][] magicSquare = {
                        {'P', 'L', 'O', 'T'},
                        {'R', 'A', 'V', 'E'},
                        {'E', 'V', 'E', 'N'},
                        {'Y', 'A', 'R', 'D'}
                       };
System.out.println(magicSquare[0][0]);
```

**Output:**
P